# A good way to always have 10 TPL tasks running & launching a new one when one completes, in a loop?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a Winform app and I am learning TPL for parallel programming. The WinForm is running continuously & spidering 10 web sites at a time. Each web site is handled by a TPL task. The tasks are independent of each other. Every time a task is done, a new task is launched. I intend to use Task.Factory.StartNew(..) for launching tasks.

I am familiar with launching TPL tasks but I am not getting a grip on how to launch multiple TPL tasks simultaneously in a loop and launching a new one every time one completes, effectively having 10 tasks always running.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a list of say 1000 urls, but you want to process no more than 10 concurrently, the simplest way to do this is to use [`Parallel::ForEach`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783747.aspx) with a [`ParallelOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.aspx) with a [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism.aspx) of 10 like so:

```
Parallel.ForEach(myListOfUrls,
    new ParallelOptions
    {
        MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10
    },
    url =>
    {
        // processing here
    });
```

Comment: This is fine if you have a fixed number of URLs at the outset. However for a web spider you will be adding things to the list.

Comment: Different problem to solve. If that was the case you would switch to a Producer/Consumer patter and myListOfUrls would just be a BlockingCollection<T> and you would spawn the Parallel::ForEach off on another task and you can keep adding to it until you're done and then call CompleteAdding. Either that or switch to using TPL Dataflow (which is what I would do) and keep posting to the target block until you're done. Lots of options.

Answer (score 0):

Use your own scheduler for the TaskFactory.

http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/article.php/c18931/

Then basiclly assign 10 threads via this scheduler.

Answer (score 0):

This is really dynamic task parallelism. Your code loops through the URLs you have and executes body on each URL. It also adds any new URLs to the queue using a addMethod and a concurrent queue.

```
public static void ParallelWhileNotEmpty<T>(
  IEnumerable<T> initialValues, 
  Action<T, Action<T>> body)
{
  var opts = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 10 };
  var from = new ConcurrentQueue<T>(initialValues);  
  while (!from.IsEmpty)
  { 
    var to = new ConcurrentQueue<T>();
    Action<T> addMethod = to.Enqueue; 
    Parallel.ForEach(from, opts. body(v, addMethod));        
    from = to;
  }
}
```

This way the "loop" is open ended and will continue until you run out of work. Obviously your real application would account for duplicate URLs and not add them etc. But this allows your to app to dynamically add work. You can use the ParallelOptions to limit concurrency or you can write a scheduler.

For more information on dynamic task parallelism see

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff963551.aspx

For the full code for the example see

http://parallelpatterns.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/54510#795590

Both of the above discuss other alternative variations on this theme.

If you want a custom scheduler to limit the degree of parallelism see the example on MSDN

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351.aspx